# Docker: how to automatically accept "Do you really want to push to public registry?"

Tags: docker, centos7

Every time I push an images on dockerhub, it ask "Do you really want to push to public registry? [y/n]".

Is there a way to automatically accept this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo y | docker push
```

Will automatically write "y" for the first question docker push asks.